# Python scrapy xpath can't reach data

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new to scrapy and I'm trying to gather image urls from a webpage, these images are located in a slide and I have no problem locating the img tags xpath with firebug on Firefox BUT as soon as I try to retrieve the data in the scrapy project or the scrapy shell I can't seem to reach it.

Furthermore, the xpath to get all img tags src attribute text does not return them.

Firebug retrieved xpath:

```
/html/body/form/div[3]/div[3]/main/div/article/section[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/img
```

Img tag format:

```
<img class="some class" scr="data I need" style="some style">
```

What I've tried :

1. To retrieve all img tags that have a src

   response.xpath('//img/@scr').extract()
2. To get the specific tag:

   response.xpath('//img[@class="some class"]/@src').extract()

I thought it has something to do with the form tag (altough I did not have problems getting athor data from the form tag or it's children) so I tryed unsuccesfully to use scrapy's form request.

Can somebody explain what aproach should I try? Is form request what I'm looking for and if not what else can cause this?

Comment: Perhaps image tags are appended to DOM dynamically using JavaScript and thus aren't part of page's HTML. In that case Scrapy can't "see" them because doesn't execute JavaScript and render DOM in context of loaded page. Check source code of the page and if there are no corresponding tags, you need to find out the way either to render JavaScript (with PhantomJS, Splash or something else) and then parse results, or reverse engineer JS.

Comment: I found the img urls on other tags when I checked the source page , it never occured to me that it could be this simple . Thank you